# I create a pdf file, send it as an attachment in the email, and when I delete it, I can't find it

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, pdf-generation, delete-file

What I am trying to do is
Generate QR code '.png' files, then generate the PDF, send an email with the generated pdf and delete the '.png's and '.pdf' afterwards

I am having trouble deleting only the '.pdf' right after I send the email, because it says the file does not exist, even though I see it in my vscode.

### pdf-bought-ticket-provider.ts

(File containing the function that generates the pdf)

```
import PDFDoc from 'pdfkit';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { container } from '@/di/container';

const pathToTemp = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'temp');
export interface IPdfTicket {
  tickets: Array<{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    filename: string;
    value: number;
    accessType: string;
  }>;
  eventName: string;
  startDateHour: string;
  payedAt: string;
  localName: string;
  localDescription: string;
  ownerTicketName: string;
  promoterAlert?: string;
}
const idGeneratorProvider = container.resolve('idGeneratorProvider');
export const pdfTicketGenerator = async (
  input: IPdfTicket,
  pathToSave: string,
): Promise<string> => {
  const doc = new PDFDoc({ autoFirstPage: false });
  const pdfName = `${idGeneratorProvider.generateUUID()}.pdf`;
  const pathToPdf = path.resolve(pathToSave, pdfName);
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(pathToPdf);
  doc.pipe(writer);
  if (input.promoterAlert) {
    doc.addPage();
    doc.fontSize(20).text('Nota do produtor:', 210, 50);
    doc.fontSize(15).text(input.promoterAlert, 50, 100);
  }
  const pdfPromise = input.tickets.map(async (ticket) => {
    // bulk of pdf write...
  });

  doc.end();
  await Promise.all(pdfPromise);

  doc.on('end', () => {
    console.log(
      'Has been writed pdf as',
      Date.now(),
      'with name starting ',
      pdfName.split('-')[0],
      fs.existsSync(path.resolve(pathToTemp, pdfName)),
      path.resolve(pathToTemp, pdfName),
    );
  });

  return pdfName;
};
```

### send-bought-ticket-email.ts

```
import {
  IsArray,
  IsDefined,
  IsEmail,
  IsNotEmptyObject,
  IsNumber,
  IsOptional,
  IsString,
  ValidateNested,
} from 'class-validator';
import { compileFile } from 'pug';
import path from 'path';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { validatorDto } from '@/validator';
import { container } from '@/di/container';
import { pdfTicketGenerator } from '@/providers/pdf/pdf-bought-ticket-provider';
import { dateFormatter } from '@/date-formatter';

const emailProvider = container.resolve('emailProvider');
const qrCodeProvider = container.resolve('qrCodeProvider');
const fileProvider = container.resolve('fileProvider');

class ITicket {
  @IsString()
  id: string;

  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  accessType: string;

  @IsNumber({ maxDecimalPlaces: 2 })
  value: number;
}

class IEvent {
  @IsString()
  id: string;

  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  banner: string;

  @IsString()
  start: string;

  @IsString()
  localName: string;

  @IsString()
  address: string;

  @IsString()
  saleType: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  producerMessage?: string;
}

class IOrder {
  @IsString()
  number: string;

  @IsString()
  paymentMethod: string;

  @IsString()
  payedAt: string;

  @IsNumber({ maxDecimalPlaces: 2 })
  value: string;
}

class IOwner {
  @IsString()
  name: string;
}
export class SendBoughtTicketEmailDTO {
  @IsEmail()
  to: string;

  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => IOwner)
  owner: IOwner;

  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => IEvent)
  event: IEvent;

  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => IOrder)
  order: IOrder;

  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsArray()
  @Type(() => ITicket)
  tickets: Array<ITicket>;
}

export const sendBoughtTicketEmail = async (input: {
  params: SendBoughtTicketEmailDTO;
}) => {
  validatorDto(SendBoughtTicketEmailDTO, input.params);
  validatorDto(IOwner, input.params.owner);
  validatorDto(IEvent, input.params.event);
  validatorDto(IOrder, input.params.order);

  input.params.tickets.map((ticket): void => validatorDto(ITicket, ticket));

  const pathToTemp = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'temp');

  const qrCodesFilenamesPromises = input.params.tickets.map(async (ticket) => {
    const qrCodeAsBase64 = await qrCodeProvider.generate(
      `${input.params.event.id}+${ticket.id}`,
    );
    const qrCodeFilename = await fileProvider.toImage(
      qrCodeAsBase64,
      pathToTemp,
    );
    return {
      id: ticket.id,
      name: ticket.name,
      filename: qrCodeFilename,
      value: ticket.value,
      accessType: ticket.accessType,
    };
  });
  const qrCodes = await Promise.all(qrCodesFilenamesPromises);

  const pdfName = await pdfTicketGenerator(
    {
      tickets: qrCodes,
      eventName: input.params.event.name,
      localDescription: input.params.event.address,
      localName: input.params.event.localName,
      ownerTicketName: input.params.owner.name.toUpperCase(),
      payedAt: dateFormatter(input.params.order.payedAt),
      startDateHour: dateFormatter(input.params.event.start),
      promoterAlert: input.params.event.producerMessage,
    },
    pathToTemp,
  );
  await Promise.all(pdfName);

  const viewPath = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    '..',
    '..',
    'views',
    'email',
    'bought-ticket.pug',
  );
  const htmlCompiler = compileFile(viewPath);
  const resolvedHtml = htmlCompiler({
    name: input.params.owner.name.toUpperCase(),
    payedAt: dateFormatter(input.params.order.payedAt),
    value: input.params.order.value,
    orderNumber: input.params.order.number,
    paymentMethod:
      input.params.order.paymentMethod === 'credit_card'
        ? 'cartão de credito'
        : input.params.order.paymentMethod,
    eventName: input.params.event.name,
    eventStart: dateFormatter(input.params.event.start),
    localName: input.params.event.localName,
    address: input.params.event.address,
    banner: input.params.event.banner,
    eventId: input.params.event.id,
    saleType: input.params.event.saleType,
    producerMessage: input.params.event.producerMessage,
    tickets: input.params.tickets,
  });

  await emailProvider.sendGeneric({
    from: input.params.event.name,
    to: input.params.to,
    subject: `Seus ingressos para o evento: ${
      input.params.event.name
    } | ${dateFormatter(input.params.event.start)} - Pedido ${
      input.params.order.number
    }`,
    html: resolvedHtml,
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: pdfName,
        contentType: 'application/pdf',
        path: path.resolve(pathToTemp, pdfName),
      },
    ],
  });
  const qrCodesUnlinkPromises = qrCodes.map(async (qrCode) => {
    const pathFile = path.resolve(pathToTemp, qrCode.filename);
    if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(pathFile);
    }
  });

  await Promise.all(qrCodesUnlinkPromises);

  console.log(
    'Checking if file exists ',
    Date.now(),
    'with name starting',
    pdfName.split('-')[0],
    fs.existsSync(path.resolve(pathToTemp, pdfName)),
  );
  if (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(pathToTemp, pdfName))) {
    fs.unlinkSync(path.resolve(pathToTemp, pdfName));
  }
};
```

Things I've already done

- check if I'm looking in the right folder
- delete after sending email (but it is not found)
- delete when pdf is finished writing (sending mail breaks obviously)
- receive as synch transform to promise
- make one while file does not exist to wait for it to finish being created (crashes node and pdf is not finished)

Comment: Does it work if you don't delete the files?

Comment: @Konrad yes, it works, but i want have a minimum files in my temp folder

Comment: Just as a sidenode: Please don't use the `...Sync` methods in an async environment. `fs` module provides a promise API for quite a while now ...

Comment: Furthermore, `await Promise.all(pdfName)` doesn't really make any sense, as  `pdfName` is a string ...

Comment: And finally: You are mixing promises with callback functions. That seldomly works out if you don't know exactly what you are doing. I suspect, at least one of the promises is resolving to early, because it doesn't wait for a callback to finish. So it might be, that you are trying to delete your file, before it's even written ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).